# equivalence relation (asking about a reminder)

Tags: calculus

It's not a question really .. just a simple relation i want to know

we know that $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ when $x \to 0$

is  $\ln(1+x^2)\sim x^2$ ? or $\ln(1+x^2)\sim x$ ? when $x \to 0$

Comment: are you using the $\mapsto$ symbol to mean when $x$ maps to 0? Or do you mean when you take the limit as $x$ goes to 0? And what are you talking about equivalence relations?

Comment: However, what I think you are saying is that $y = ln(1+x)$ is appx. the function $y = x$ when $x = 0$. If this is the case, simply graphing the functions should help you answer your question

Comment: more like $ln(1+x^{2})= x$ i hope u can understand and equivalence or equivalent relations idk how you name it in your country but since i study in french i just translated it by google lol anyway i hope u understood what i wrote there and about the $x$ more like the limit as $x$ goes to $0$

Comment: In any country an equivalence relation is a relation that is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation

Comment: But yes, then you are asking what I thought. Just graph them! You'll see your answer

Comment: It seems $x\to0$ rather than $x\mapsto0$ must have been intended, so I changed it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy i dont know the difference but yeah if its correct thank you

Comment: @AymanErroutabi : The notation $x\mapsto x^2$ means the function that squares its input and returns that as the output.

Comment: @MichaelHardy ooh right i do know now thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: remember the definition of $\sim$ and think of it as a substitution $y=x^2$ where $x \to 0$ iff $y\to 0$: $$1 = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+y)}{y} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2} $$

Comment: thats exactly what what i was looking for thank you man

Answer (score 3):

When we say $\ln(1+x)\sim_0 x$ (`ln(1+x) is equivalent to x near 0`), it has a precise meaning, which is *not* ‘is approximately equal to $x$’ (incidentally, this is not a mathematical notion). The exact meaning  is
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1. $$
Hence $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2}=1,\quad\text{so}\quad\ln(1+x^2)\sim_0 x^2.$$

Note that, at $\infty$, it may very well happen that two functions are equivalent, but their difference does not tend to $0$: for instance $x+\sqrt x\sim_\infty x$, but $\;(x+\sqrt x)-x\to +\infty$ when $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the definition.

Comment: $\quad\ln(1+x^2)\sim_0 x^2$ thats the exact form i wanted to type but couldnt thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(1+x^2)$ plotted against $x^2$

[image]

$\ln(1+x^2)$ plotted against $x$

[image]

Comment: Note the proper notation: $\ln(1+x^2)$, not $ln(1+x^2)$. Code this as \ln(1+x^2). This not only prevents italicization, but also results in proper spacing in things like $x\ln y$ or $x\ln(y)$. I include both of those last examples so you can see the context-dependent nature of the spacing.

Comment: Great, thanks. It looks so much better.

Comment: oh right thanks guys for the efforts i understand more now thank you